# A classic stars and bars problem

Tags: combinatorics

We have $n$ spaces to be filled with stars or bars. How many ways are there to do this using $k \space (k<n/2)$ stars if between every two star there has to be at least one stick? Also, how many ways can we arrange them if we can have as many stars as we want (but (clearly) fewer than $n/2+1$)?

Comment: So, you want the number of ways $a_k$ of arranging $k \leq \lceil n/2 \rceil$ stars in $n$ cells such that no two stars are adjacent, and then also the sum of $a_k$ for $k = 0$ to $\lceil n/2 \rceil$?

Comment: Yes it can even be n/2+1 if n is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: Write down the $k$ stars, with some space between them. Insert a bar between consecutive stars. So we have $n-k-(k-1)$ bars left over. There are $k+1$ places into which we need to insert $0$ or more bars. So we are counting the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_{k+1}=n-2k+1$ in non-negative integers.

Second problem (rough sketch): The more familiar version counts the number of binary strings of length $n$ with no two consecutive $0$'s. Let $a_n$ be the number of such strings. By looking separately at strings of length $n+1$ that end with a $1$, and those that end in a $0$. we obtain the familiar Fibonacci recurrence $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, and is there an easy formula for counting the non-negative solutions in the first part?

Comment: Yes, there is. I did not write it down because I assumed you were familiar with standard Stars and Bars, as described in say Wikipedia. The number of solutions of $x+1+\cdots+x_m=w$ in non-negative integers is $\binom{w+m-1}{m-1}$. Take $m=k+1$ and $w=n-2k+1$. Of course we need $w\ge 0$.

Comment: Please note the typo in the comment above, above, it should be $x_1+\cdots+x_m=w$.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for explaining.

Comment: You are welcome. There are two basic Stars and Bars formulas, of which it is only necessary to know one, since they are related. The number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_m=w$ in non-negative integers is $\binom{m+w-1}{m-1}$. The number of solutions in positive integers is $\binom{w-1}{m-1}$. They come up a lot, so it is important not only to know them, but also to know *why* they are correct.  For without knowing the why, it is all too easy to not remember them quite right.

Comment: Thank you, it's now clear to me that it comes from a very simple stars and bars case.